# How to make Outlook to not save outgoing attachments

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook

When a message is sent in Outlook, the message is saved in the appropriate sent items folder. In an effort to keep mailbox sizes small(er), we would like to see if there is a way to automatically strip any attachments from outgoing saved messages. This doesn't need to be implemented via group policy or anything, it's just something we're looking into at this point.

Is this possible to do in Outlook 2010 or 2013 (either Windows 7 or 8.1)?

Answer (score 0):

Source [Remove attachments from messages](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/remove-attachments-from-sent-messages/)

> This question from Outlook user wanted to know how to remove several
>   attachments from a message in one step.
>
> I want to keep sent messages but not the attachments. Is there an
>   easier method than clicking on the attachment to delete it? Better
>   yet, can I select several sent messages and remove the attachments
>   from all of the messages?
>
> Outlook doesn't have this functionality built in so you'll need to use
>   an add-in or VBA, but yes, it can be done.
>
> See [Attachment Management Tools for Outlook](http://www.slipstick.com/addins/auto-process/attachment-management-tools-for-outlook/) for add-ins or [More
>   Information](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/remove-attachments-from-sent-messages/#more) for additional macros, including code samples that can
>   save the attachments to the hard drive before deleting them from the
>   message.
>
> **This code will work with sent or received messages, in any folder.** To use, [add the code to the VBA editor](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/), **select the messages
>   that you want to delete the attachment from and run it.**

```
Sub DeleteAllAttachmentsFromSelectedMessages()
    Dim myAttachment        As Attachment
    Dim myAttachments       As Attachments
    Dim selItems            As Selection
    Dim myItem              As Object
    Dim lngAttachmentCount  As Long

    ' Set reference to the Selection.
    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    '  Loop though each item in the selection.
    For Each myItem In selItems
        Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

        lngAttachmentCount = myAttachments.Count

    ' Loop through attachments until attachment count = 0.
        While lngAttachmentCount > 0
            myAttachments(1).Delete
            lngAttachmentCount = myAttachments.Count
        Wend

        myItem.Save
    Next

    MsgBox "All Done. Attachments were removed.", vbOKOnly, "Message"

    Set myAttachment = Nothing
    Set myAttachments = Nothing
    Set selItems = Nothing
    Set myItem = Nothing
End Sub
```